# Merge lots of rasters in r using do.call

Tags: r, merge, r-raster

I am dealing MODIS MOD15A2H datasets and want to merge all the tiles of layer one together. I use gdal_translate() to convert .hdf layer into .tif file. And try to use do.call(merge, tiflist) to merge ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226351/combine-multiple-partially-overlapping-rasters-into-a-single-raster-in-r)). I find it so wield that the value of cells would change when the length of list is more than 5. (Update: I find there's nothing to do with 5. Sometimes it goes wrong with 4 files while arbitrary three of them go well. But for other files, there is no such problem.) Could anyone help with that? Just don't know why and in which situation do.call has such problem.

I change fun from mosaic to merge in my case since there is no overlapping problem.

```
#transform to tif
for (i in 1:length(hdffilenames)){
  gdal_translate(sdsnames[i,1], dst_dataset = paste("fpar_",substr(sdsnames[i,1],37,42),".tif",sep = ""))}
tifnames=paste("fpar_",substr(sdsnames[,1],37,42),".tif",sep = "")
h=as.integer(substr(sdsnames[,1],38,39))
subtifnames=list()
for (i in seq(1:36)){
  subtifnames[i]=tifnames[h=i]
}

#merge function
mergetifList <- function(tifList){
  
  #Internal function to make a list of raster objects from list of files.
  ListRasters <- function(list_names) {
    raster_list <- list() # initialise the list of rasters
    for (i in 1:(length(list_names))){ 
      tif_name <- list_names[i] # list_names contains all the names of the images in .tif format
      raster_file <- raster::raster(tif_name)
      raster_file[raster_file>1] <- NA
    }
    raster_list <- append(raster_list, raster_file) # update raster_list at each iteration
    return(raster_list)
    }
  
  #convert every raster path to a raster object and create list of the results
  raster.list <-sapply(tifList, FUN = ListRasters)
  
  # edit settings of the raster list for use in do.call and merge
  names(raster.list) <- NULL
  #####This function deals with overlapping areas
  #raster.list$fun <- max
  #run do call to implement mosaic over the list of raster objects.
  mergeRas <- do.call(raster::merge, raster.list)
  
  return(mergeRas)
}
```

and then I use some lists to test:

```
 > tifname1=c("fpar_h29v09.tif", "fpar_h29v10.tif", "fpar_h29v11.tif", "fpar_h29v12.tif", "fpar_h29v13.tif")
    > m_1=mergetifList(tifname1)
    > plot(m_1)
```

[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzuAJ.png)

```
> tifname2=c
("fpar_h29v08.tif", "fpar_h29v09.tif", "fpar_h29v10.tif", "fpar_h29v11.tif", "fpar_h29v12.tif")
> m_2=mergetifList(tifname2)
> plot(m_2)
```

[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exXyQ.png)

```
> tifname3=c("fpar_h29v08.tif", "fpar_h29v09.tif", "fpar_h29v10.tif", "fpar_h29v11.tif", "fpar_h29v12.tif","fpar_h29v13.tif")
> m_3=mergetifList(tifname3)
> plot(m_3)
```

[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wjFf.png)

Thanks very much!

Comment: You may be seeing a variation of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940820/how-to-replicate-ggplot2geom-raster-in-base-graphics/43016575#43016575. Try changing the "maxpixels" value in the call to `plot`. By the way: for that kind of processing you may also consider using the `MODIStsp` package: http://lbusett.github.io/MODIStsp/

Comment: @LoBu Thanks for your kind reply! I don't think it is a problem of plotting since when I check the values of the merged raster, values do change. Now I just use "merge" one by one. And I appreciate your info for MODIStsp. The problem is that I am not sure how it changes the projection and resolution. I don't find a place to see its source code.  I prefer to do it by myself.

Comment: That's strange... Concerning MODIStsp, all changes in projection in resolution (if needed) are based on standard calls to gdalwarp / gdaltranslate. If you're interested, source code can be found on the main github page of the project: https://github.com/lbusett/MODIStsp

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't notice there is source code in that website. I am quite new to this field and we are trying to create a new product, thus we want to make sure every step goes as we wish. It's also better to estimate the error.